Can I use two sets of bluetooth headphones on the same system?
I am wondering if there's an easy way to have multiple sets of Bluetooth headsets (earbuds or headphones) work simultaneously on the same system?  For instance, if I want to watch a movie with someone but we both want to be wearing earbuds instead of listening to speakers?
(Edit, can't believe I forgot to put this in: Lubuntu 22.04LTS.  It apparently doesn't already use pulse-audio and I've had loads of audio headache in the past.  Would this paprefs package work on the default audio server?  It looks promising, but I don't want to install pulseaudio and suddenly get stuck without audio.)

What version of Ubuntu and what have you tried so far?

Does this answer your question? Play sound through two or more outputs/devices

Thank you, @David, I did a Homer Simpson and forgot to mention I'm on Lubuntu 22.04LTS.  I haven't really tried anything thus far, other than opening the default audio Mixer and seeing if there's anything obvious.  (I didn't see anything.)

@graham, thank you, this looks promising but I'm curious if it will work in Lubuntu, which doesn't seem to run on PulseAudio.  But I know very little about audio so maybe it's fine?

only one way to find out

@graham far too old to my liking, pipewire is the default in newer Ubuntu and the audio server to use.
